# How to know when a dll is removed from the GAC

Tags: gac

From times to time when PC restarts, some dll from the GAC are removed. I am sure it's not a manual operation. How can I find how and when the dll are removed ?

NB : after each restart, I manually add the dll by drag and dropping them to C:\WINNT\assembly